# Subset of a compact set $A_{\epsilon}^{f}$ is compact.

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Let $X$ be a topological space.
Let $U$ be open in $X$.
For $\epsilon >0$, and $f:U\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ define $$A_{\epsilon}^f=\{x\in U \;|\; |f(x)|\geq \epsilon\}$$
and $$C_o(U)=\{f:U\rightarrow \mathbb{R} \text{ is continuous }\;|\; \forall \epsilon>0,A_{\epsilon}^f \text{ is a compact subset in }U\}$$

Suppose $U,V$ are open subsets of $X$ such that $U\subseteq V$.
Suppose $f\in C_o(V)$.
Prove that $f|_U\in C_o(U)$.

Since $f\in C_o(V)$, $f$ is continuous.
I have shown that $f|_U$ is continuous.
Let $\epsilon>0$.
I want to prove that $A_{\epsilon}^{f|_U}$ is a compact subset in $U$.
First I notice that $A_{\epsilon}^{f|_U} \subseteq A_{\epsilon}^{f}$.
Next I proved that $A_{\epsilon}^{f|_U}$ is closed in $U$.
Thus if $A_{\epsilon}^{f|_U}$ is closed in $A_{\epsilon}^{f}$, $A_{\epsilon}^{f|_U}$ is compact since it is a closed subset of $A_{\epsilon}^{f}$ which is compact.

Comment: It seems that it is not immediately obvious that element in $C_0(U)$ is continuous. The definition of $C_0(U)$ has never mentioned the continuity of $f$.

Comment: @DannyPak-KeungChan Sorry my mistake. The elements in $C_o(U)$ are defined to be continuos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the proposition is false. We consider the following
counter-example.

Let $X=\mathbb{R}$ equipped with the usual topology. Define $f:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$
by 
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}
0, & \mbox{ if }x<-2\\
x+2, & \mbox{ if }-2\leq x\leq0\\
-x+2, & \mbox{ if }0\leq x<2\\
0, & \mbox{ if }x\geq2
\end{cases}
$$

Let $V=(-10,10)$ and $U=(-1,1)$. $U$, $V$ are open subsets
of $X$ with $U\subseteq V$. Define $g=f\vert_{V}$. Clearly $g$ is continuous.

It can be verified that for any $\varepsilon>0$, $A_{\varepsilon}^{g}$
is either empty or of the form $[-a,a]$ for some $a\in[0,2)$. Note that $[-a,a]$ is a compact subset in $V$. Hence,
$g\in C_{0}(V)$.

Define $h=g\vert_{U}$. Take $\varepsilon=0.2$. Then $A_{\varepsilon}^{h}=(-1,1)$,
which is not a compact subset in $U$. Therefore $g\vert_{U}\notin C_{0}(U)$.

Comment: should consider $g=f|_U$ isn't it?

Comment: Typo. I just fix it.

Comment: Another counter-example: Let $X=V=[0,3]$ with the usual topology. Every continuous $f:V\to \Bbb R$ belongs to $C_0(V)$  because $ V$ is a compact Hausdorff space. Let $U=[0,2)$ and let $f(x)=x$ for all $x\in V.$ Then $U\cap f^{-1}[1,\infty)=[1,2)$  is not compact.